# Добавить на сайт голосовое общение

Tags: веб-программирование, аудио, потоки-данных

Необходимо на сайт добавить голосовое общение с другим посетителем, но не знаю за что зацепится, какие технологии необходимо изучать, в какую сторону двигаться. Что можете посоветовать? Можно ли обойтись без flash?